# How to replace existing Curl version with an updated one using Cygwin?

Tags: curl, cygwin

I already have curl 7.40.0 installed on my windows. I downloaded the latest curl package from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html and I unziped it into my Downloads directory. Now I have a usr directory in my Downloads. Location of curl.exe is Downloads/usr/bin/curl.exe. I want to replace my existing curl (/cygdrive/c/Program Files/cURL/bin/curl this I got by typing "which curl" on terminal) on my system with this new version which is in the Downloads. How do I do it?

Comment: have you tried `rm '/cygdrive/c/Program Files/cURL/bin/curl'; mv 'Downloads/usr/bin/curl.exe' '/cygdrive/c/Program Files/cURL/bin/curl';` ?

Comment: also you could probably just update your cygwin installation, the cygwin installer is also like an update manager after it's already installed. the current cygwin curl release is 7.59.0, and that's also the very latest curl release, as of writing, so cygwin's release is 100% up to date right now.

Comment: Hi @hanshenrik I have not tried what you said in the first point. I installed apt-cyg which is used to install packages in cygwin and then I typed command "apt-cyg install curl" It started downloading and unpacking the latest package which is 7.59 and skipped the packages that were already there and installed curl. But when I again checked the version of curl it was still 7.40

Comment: download and run http://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe , don't tell it to install anything new, just press "next next next next", it should update all your existing cygwin packages, including curl.

Comment: If you're using Cygwin then you should use the Cygwin package for cURL, either via a recent `setup-*.exe` or via `apt-cyg` as others have suggested.  Cygwin is something of a closed ecosystem: Although it's perfectly possible to run non-Cygwin executables from within a Cygwin-based shell, you'll find that they don't necessarily interface as well as one might like with Cygwin-based executables.  This has nothing to do with "bash" per se as it's just the default shell shipped with Cygwin and doesn't have much to do with how packages for Cygwin are installed.